# symfony create database index with lower function

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, postgresql-9.4

How can I declare in Doctrine an index for postgresql like:
CREATE INDEX index_name_city_hotel ON booking_hotels(lower(name) text_pattern_ops, city_hotel, cc1)

I already tried but it seems impossible to use lower() function.
This doesn't work because of the lower function:

```
indexes={
@ORM\Index(name="index_name_city_hotel", columns={"lower(name) text_pattern_ops", "city_hotel", "cc1"})
```

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I would use a `NONE` strategy (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies) and generate the wanted id in a pre-persist event function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://github.com/intaro/custom-index-bundle

```
<?php

namespace Acme\MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Intaro\CustomIndexBundle\Annotations as CustomIndexAnnotation

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_entity")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @CustomIndexAnnotation\CustomIndexes(indexes={
 *     @CustomIndexAnnotation\CustomIndex(columns="my_property1"),
 *     @CustomIndexAnnotation\CustomIndex(columns={"lower(my_property1)", "lower(my_property2)"})
 * })
 */
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=256)
     */
    protected $myProperty1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=256)
     */
    protected $myProperty2;
}
```